# Christoffel symbols of second kind derivation and relation

Tags: differential-geometry

If I got it right, Christoffel symbols of second kind are defined in two ways, namely:-

(1). $\Gamma^i_{jk}=\frac{g^{im}}{2}\bigl(\frac{\partial g_{jm}}{\partial x^k}+\frac{\partial g_{mk}}{\partial x^j}-\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial x^m}\bigr)$

and

(2). $\Gamma^i_{jk}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^m}\frac{\partial^2x^m}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}$

Now what I am unable to get is if the two definition are equivalent, how can we derive one from the other, i.e. how can we derive (1) from (2) or vice-versa?

Comment: It's not clear what does $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^m}$ mean. What are $x^i$'s?

Comment: Check e.g. [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChristoffelSymboloftheSecondKind.html), line (47) for the correct formulation of your (2). Rewriting $g$ in terms of $x$ and $\xi$, in  the notation there, and carrying out all the derivations will get you the equality.

Answer (score -1):

Very briefly: they are not equivalent. Christoffel symbols characterize the Levi-Civita connection of the metric. Formula (1) is correct, but formula (2) has no chance of being correct because it does not involve the metric whatsoever. In the non-linear transformation law between Christoffel symbols associated to different coordinate systems, you do have a term similar to what appears in (2), but this is not $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ nor $\Gamma_{ijk}$.